# Must a UICollectionViewController's UICollectionView be its root UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

In a storyboard, I'd like to describe a `UICollectionViewController` that has a plain `UIView` as its root view (the `view` parameter). The root view will be a container holding the `UICollectionView` as a child, with another `UIView` in front of it.

(I want to place my own `UIGestureRecognisers` in front of the `UIColellectionView`'s to pick up pans and pinches. I'll disable the  `UIColellectionView`'s "User Interaction").

The storyboard editor doesn't seem to want me to do this if I drag a `UICollectionViewController` from the "Object Library". Can it be done? Would I be better off subclassing from `UIViewController` instead of `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: Why don't you drag a `UIViewController` in storyboard and add a `UICollectionView` in it? Then, inside it you can put the `UIView` you need and the `UICollectionView` as well.

Comment: dragging UICollectionViewController or collectionView ??

Comment: @CainaSouza Great minds think alike! :-) I gave this a try just now, but it doesn't work. Xcode's run time error is that the view the storyboard is instantiating for UICollectionViewController is of the wrong type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very short answer to the questions: Yes, it must. `UICollectionViewController` requires it's `[self view]` to be the `UICollectionView` instance.

Instead of doing this, have a top level `UIViewController` owning the `UICollectionViewController` as a child. This suitably separates the code / logic / ownership of each of the views and correctly allocates controllers for each section of your 'view'.

- If you are setting up from code, use `UIViewController` as the owner of the top level `view` and use `addChildViewController:` to handle the nested collection view controller.
- If you are setting up from a storyboard, have a `UIViewController` scene that has a view hierarchy of your choosing but includes a "Container View" object from the storyboard editor's "Object Library" somewhere in it. Have the `UICollectionViewController` in a separate scene. Point the "Container View" you added at the `UICollectionViewController`'s scene in the storyboard.

Comment: I'm giving this a go. I'm not explicitly using `addChildViewController:`, but instead using the Storyboard concept of a "Container View". Is this the same thing in the end? If it is, I'd like to extend your answer to mention this approach if that's okay with you. I like the separation of concerns that splitting the controllers gives.

Comment: Yes, that would be the way of configuring it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewController` Is a lot more restrictive than `UICollectionView`. Same goes for `UITableViewController`. `UITableViewController` for example won't let you add another UIView to it without effecting to the `UITableView` hierarchy table view.

As a matter effect, I hardly use those `ViewControllers` and always prefer to use the original `UICollectionView`.

Just drag a `UIViewController` to your story board and drag a `UICollectionView` on top of it.